# Why does not ListLinePlot work with a new defined ColorFunction?

Tags: plotting, color

I would like to use ListLinePlot with data from excel file but it does not work! However, ListPlot is working fine?! Below is  the code I used

```
colorBar[arg_] := Blend[{Red, Green, Blue}, Rescale[arg, {-1, 1}]];
postE = Table[{x, 0.05 + Cos[x]^2, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 30, 0.05}];  
ListLinePlot[{Style[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, colorBar[#[[3]]]] & /@ postE}]   
ListPlot[{Style[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, colorBar[#[[3]]]] & /@ postE}]
```

Comment: What is the definition of `colorBar`?

Comment: @BobHanlon I added it to the code

Comment: Please define "but it does not work!".  Are there error messages?  Also, you'd certainly need to define `colorBar` prior to using it.  Moving the `colorBar` definition to the beginning of your code above produces a perfectly fine graph.

Comment: @JimB, `ListLinePlot`  gives only one color but I need the color to be as in the `ListPlot`

Comment: But that's what you need to describe in your question.  "it does not work!" doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color of the line in [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) is controlled by the option [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html)

```
postE = Table[{x, 0.05 + Cos[x]^2, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 30, 0.05}];

colorBar[arg_] := Blend[{Red, Green, Blue}, Rescale[arg, {-1, 1}]]
```

If you know the third element is `Cos[x]` then

```
ListLinePlot[postE[[All, 1 ;; 2]],
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, colorBar[Cos[x]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

If you don't know the functional value then use

```
ListLinePlot[postE[[All, 1 ;; 2]],
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, colorBar[postE[[Position[postE[[All, 1]], x][[1, 1]], 3]]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx a lot @Bob